# Searches with complex keyword sets

Tags: eventbrite

I'd like to make more robust searches by including keyword variants. The api doesn't appear to support wild cards or automatically include variants. Can someone at Eventbrite explain how to get the most out of the keyword parameter?  Also, how are multiple keywords handled? Can a search handle doublets or longer sets? Can a search be done with boolean operators?

So far, I have only seen very simple searches (single word) working. What can I do to get more from this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventbrite uses [Apache Lucene / SOLR](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) for it's search back-end.
This provides basic keyword stemming features and full-text search over the event title and description.

By default, multiple keywords are handled with an 'AND' operator: 
Searching for 'bikes' and 'tacos' (keywords=bikes%20tacos), should return all events that mention "taco" or "tacos" AND "bike" or "bikes".  Keyword stemming support allows you to automatically match on most english-language pluralizations.

If you want to find all events that mention either 'bikes' OR 'tacos', you can separate your keywords with an 'OR' clause (keywords=bikes%20OR%20tacos).

The [event_search](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/events/event_search/) API documentation page should contain the most recent information on how to use this method's keyword parameter.
You should be able to test your queries using the interactive 'Try it Now!' section located on that page.

Comment: Thanks, Ryan. Will keyword stemming revert a keyword from its plural or other form (for example, -s, -es, -ing) into the base word. For example, would "hikes" and "hiking" revert to "hike" and expanding on the base word?

Comment: I tested three calls to [event_search](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/events/event_search/) (with 'count_only' set to 'true') in order to find the answer to this question.  
'hike', 'hikes', and 'hiking' all returned the same number of event results.  It looks like stemming is working correctly for the variations of 'hike' that you have listed here.

Comment: I'm trying to find fashion and comedy events.  

keywords=fashion returns 6 events, 
keywords=comedy returns 4 events, 
keywords=fashion%20OR%20comedy returns 5 completely different events than what fashion or comedy returned

not sure what i'm doing wrong. any ideas?

Comment: I'm getting back over 3,500 events with those search terms.  Please send your request URL via email and I'd be happy to help troubleshoot! (api@eventbrite)